# How to cache sql queries, the result of which never change?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, caching

I have three tables - `Countries`, `USRegions` and `Regions`. For the different countries `Regions` holds a particular administrative division of the territory of that country. For the US these are the 50 states and Washington, D.C.. So again:

```
Countries - USA, Germany, Japan etc.
USRegions - Pacific, Middle Atlantic, South Atlantic (a total of 9 rows)
Regions - Virginia, Texas etc., but also similar divisions for other countries, like regional cities for Poland etc.
```

In one of the views I have a form, where the user can select certain US Regions and certain States. So in order to display the names of these, I make two calls to the database. One with all rows to the `USRegions` table and one with all rows with `country_id = USA.id` to the `Regions` table. The thing is - the result of these calls will always be the same (unless there are new states, which is very unlikely, although [possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Californias)). So is there a way to cache these calls and if yes - how and where?

Comment: I meant the 50 states + Washington, D.C.. I'll correct that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails automatically caches the SQL queries if it encounters the same query again. Here is the reference link for this. [SQL Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching).  If still you want to cache it then you can use [Low Level Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching). Use a key based caching it would do the work.

Comment: So I guess I need to use low-level caching, because I need to cache the query between requests and not for that particular request.

Comment: Yes exactly. Check the console too when you are on the view without caching, and make the same query execute again and again you will find once it will load and then it will always load from cache.